# Static Qt build causing segmentation fault when compiling/running

Tags: c++, qt, compiler-errors, segmentation-fault, qt-creator

I have created a static build of Qt by following this guide (https://wiki.qt.io/Building_a_static_Qt_for_Windows_using_MinGW) and when I go to compile/run the application I get the following:

```
22:53:54: The program has unexpectedly finished.
22:53:54: The process was ended forcefully.
```

I then ran the Qt debugger and received the following error:

> The inferior stopped because it received a signal from the operating
> system
>
> Signal Name: SIGSEGV
>
> Signal meaning: Segmentation fault

**Can't provide the assembly from the debugger as it isn't displaying**

I then tried to build the application with normal MinGW 32bit compiler and it compiles and runs fine so I presume the issue is located within my static build of Qt.

When compiling Qt statically I didn't receive any errors, so I can't provide any error information on the actual compiling on Qt.

**Steps to reproduce**

- Follow this guide (https://youtu.be/lwX_urJJOf8?t=750) as well as (https://wiki.qt.io/Building_a_static_Qt_for_Windows_using_MinGW)
- Then create a new Qt project and attempt to run it

**My Qt configuration:**

- Compiler: MinGW 32bit
- Qt version: 5.12.1
- Build tool: qmake
- qt statically built

Comment: SIGSEGV is a pretty generic crash, the app trying to access memory it doesn't own. What application are you actually trying to compile+run? Qt is a library/API, not an app, so your question needs more information to help us know what you actually tried to compile and run.

Comment: @Aiken Drum I tried compiling and running a fresh project. File->new project->qt widget application. I didnt change anything in the generated files i just ran it as it was created